# Instanciar clases abstractas en Java

Tags: java

Cada vez que quiero crear un objeto de una clase abstracta con dos hijas, me crea el constructor implementando el método.

```
package ultimaIntentona;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class Personal {

    static int  autonumerico;
    int numPersonal;
    String nombre;
    Cliente cliente;
    String registroPersonal;
    double sueldoBase;
    ArrayList<Proyecto> proyectosAsignados;

    public Personal() {//mis datos
        this.autonumerico++;
        this.numPersonal = autonumerico;
        this.nombre = "pepe";
        this.cliente = new Cliente();
        this.registroPersonal = "123a";
        this.sueldoBase = 3000.0;
        this.proyectosAsignados = new ArrayList<Proyecto>();
    }

    public abstract double calcularSueldo();
```

Tiene dos clases hijas:

La primera,

```
package ultimaIntentona;

public class Programadores extends Personal{
    double sueldo;

    public Programadores(double sueldo) {
        this.sueldo = sueldo;
    }

    @Override
    public double calcularSueldo() {
        this.sueldo=getSueldoBase();
        return sueldo;
    }
```

Y la otra hija

```
package ultimaIntentona;

public class Responsables extends Personal {
    double sueldo;
    int productividad;

public Responsables(int productividad) {
    super();
    this.productividad = productividad;
}

@Override
public double calcularSueldo() {
    this.sueldo=getSueldoBase()+productividad;
    return sueldo;
}
```

Y cada vez que construyo un objeto me obliga a implementar el método. Por ejemplo:

[[image: Captura del llamado al constructor]]

Answer (score 2):

Cuando instrancias una clase abstracta, es como si utlizaras una clase "incompleta" ya que falta la implementación de los métodos abstractos, Java te permite en ese caso crear una clase anonima para utlizarla pero te obliga a definir los métodos abstractos pendientes. Finalmente si no deseas implementar dichos métodos, puedes utilizar una de las clases hijas que has definido. Por ejemplo:

```
Programadores p = new Programadores();

Responsables r = new Responsables();
```

> An abstract class is a class that is declared abstract—it may or may
>   not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated,
>   but they can be subclassed.
>
> An abstract method is a method that is declared without an
>   implementation (without braces, and followed by a semicolon)
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

En español: una clase abstracta es una clase que se declara con la palabra clave abtracta y puede o no contener métodos abstractos. Una clase abstracta no puede ser instanciada pero puede heredar.

Un método abstracto es un método que es declarado sin implementación (sin corchetes y seguido por un punto y coma)

Answer (score 0):

No se puede instanciar una clase abstracta, por su propia naturaleza, es decir al menos contiene un método abstracto para que sea abstracto.

Lo que se tiene que hacer es instanciar desde las clases hijas que heredan de la clase "padre" en tu caso sería instanciar desde las clases Programadores o Responsables.

Si instancias de la clase Persona, no tendría sentido haber hecho la herencia ni la clase abstracta.

Answer (score 0):

Jamás vas a poder instanciar una clase abstracta. Esa es su función y por naturaleza **ni se puede ni se debe instanciar**. Una clase abstracta, como bien estás comprendiendo se utiliza para "dotar" de ciertas propiedades y funciones a una clase hija la cual si se podrá instanciar. Quedaría algo como esto:

```
Programadores programador = new Programadores();
Responsables responsable = new Responsables();
```

Estas dos instancias, son clases distintas pero tienen una cosa en común y es que ambas **heredan** de Personal. Por ende, ambas tendrán un padre común y además estarán heredando las propiedades de este y las funciones y/o **implementaciones** que dicte el padre.

Puedes indagar mucho más en los JavaDocs.

> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html